# iOS app not asking for permissions on iOS7 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios-permissions

I have an iOS app with push notifications enabled using following code

```
 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

When this app is run on iOS9 device it asks for permissions in the beginning just fine, but when used on iOS7 , iPhone 4 it doesn't ask for permissions but it receives the notifications just fine, not able to understand the issue.

Comment: If your app has already obtained permissions for an operation, it does not ask for it any longer unless the device is reset or app is uninstalled for at least a day. Are you sure you haven't granted your app permissions for push on that iPhone 4 previously?

Comment: User says he was never asked for one

Comment: Which means that the app does have permissions, albeit prior to installation of the app. He could not possibly receive any push without giving permissions. Ask the user to check permissions for the app in settings menu. He probably just uninstalled the previous build but instantly the latest build that you gave him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as your user is receiving the push notifications despite not being presented a permission dialogue, following must be the scenario:

1. He had a previous build on his iPhone 4s which he had authorized for push notifications.
2. He quickly uninstalled the previous build and installed the latest build you gave him, without giving a period of one day to device before reinstalling.
3. Result was that he wasn't presented any dialogue asking for push notifications permissions as the permissions were already granted previously.

According to [Apple Technical Note 2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42):

> The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications,
>   iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app.
>   **Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again
>   unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at
>   least a day.**
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave
>   the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without
>   actually waiting a day by following these steps:
>
> Delete your app from the device. Turn the device off completely and
>   turn it back on. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the
>   date ahead a day or more. Turn the device off completely again and
>   turn it back on

If you ask your user to check for app specific permissions in settings menu, He will certainly see the Push permissions. Otherwise he would not have been receiving push notifications at all.